# display form fields data stored in DB mysql

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

i'm new from mysql, i'm working with joomla 2.5, through a form module i'm collecting values from 2 fields, these values (item1, item2) are correctly stored in mysql tables (item1, item2) plus there should be automatically stored the userID and the email.
Now i can correctly save in a table the values and the email but not the userID (of the current user in joomla), whan i call these values everithing is ok until i try to filter by the user (or user email - mysql WHERE command), i've attempted different syntax without results.

```
here's the mysql table (jos_schede)
id;  item1;    item2;   item3;
1;   value1;   value2;  email1 (current user email) 
2;   value3;   value4;  email2 (different user email) 
here i would like to store in another column the userID (current user)
```

and this is the script i've added in joomla to extract the db values

```
<?php 
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); 
?>

<?php echo('the values are'); ?><br />
<?php

$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$userEmail = $user->get( 'email' );
$userID = $user->get( 'id' );

//connect to the server
$link = mysql_connect ("myhost", "myuser", "mypw");
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

//connect to the database
mysql_select_db ("mydatabase");

//query the database
$query = mysql_query("SELECT item1, item2, item3, id FROM jos_schede, jos_users WHERE    item3='*currentemail*'");

//fetch the results / convert results into an array
    WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

    $id = $rows['id'];
        $item1 = $rows['item1'];
        $item2 = $rows['item2'];
    $item3 = $rows['item3'];

    echo "$userID<br>$item1<br>$item2<br>item3";

    endwhile;
?>
```

---

could someone tell me where i'm wrong? thank you!

Comment: Could you add specific error details?

Comment: hi, thank you for the support, there's no error in the script: when i remove WHERE    item3='currentemail' i get all the values stored in DB, and when i put the same filter (SELECT..FROM..WHERE) no one data is displayed - while instead the scrip shold recognize the current user by the email and return only the his own values...

Comment: hi, adding  WHERE id='userID' at the end of the SELECT...FROM i get this error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/mhd-01/www.site.eu/htdocs/dir/modules/mod_modname/tmpl/example.php on line 37